# generate thumbnail of pdf document using acrobat 7.0 sdk

Tags: c#, sdk, bitmap, acrobat

how to generate image of 1st page from pdf document using acrobat 7.0 sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using acrobat will be fairly inefficient and slow.

GhostScript can be used to do this (its free to run on your own server) http://www.ghostscript.com/

Or components like the [**PDFRasterizer.NET**](http://www.tallcomponents.com)